# Copying files from directory via multiprocessing and shutil python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

`shutil` provides one of the simplest ways to copy files/folders
from a directory to another.

A simple way of doing this is by:

```
# Source path
src = r'D:\source_path'  
# Destination path  
dest = r'C:\destination_path\new_folder'
# Copy the content of source to destination  
destination = shutil.copytree(src, dest)
```

The problem with above is it copies each individual files one after another. And for directory containing a thousand files, and let along one in an distant server, this becomes difficult and time consuming.

Implementing `multiprocessing` to this task will solve a lot of pain and time.
I am aware of basic use of multiprocessing features but not sure how to proceed. I would think to start like this:

```
import multiprocessing 
import os 

def copy_instance(): 
    # printing process id 
    destination = shutil.copytree(src, dest) 
  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # printing main program process id 
    print("ID of main process: {}".format(os.getpid())) 
  
    # creating processes 
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=copy_instance) 
  
    # starting processes 
    p1.start()
```

But this doesn't solve anything in the sense of applying each file as a separate run. Any help, suggestion or links will be helpful.

**Edit:** Also tried this, but couldn't make it work. Any suggestion.

```
import multiprocessing 
import os 
import shutil
  
def copy_instance(list): 
    dest = r'C:\destination_path\new_folder'
    destination = shutil.copytree(list, dest) 
    return destination
  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # input list 
    
    sec = r"D:\source_path"
    source = os.listdir(sec)
    list=[]
    for ith in range(len(source)):
        list.append(str(sec) + "\\" + str(source[ith]))
    # creating a pool object 
    p = multiprocessing.Pool() 
  
    # map list to target function 
    result = p.map(copy_instance, list) 
  
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you coded doesn't solve the problem because you're not using multiprocessing properly. The last two lines is just creating a single process to copy the files and it's working like you didn't do anything, I mean as if you didn't use multiprocessing, so what you have to do is creating multiple process to copy the files and one solution could be create one process per file and to do that you'll have to add some steps and stop using `copytree` as follow:

```
import shutil
import multiprocessing 
import os

def copy_instance(file): 

    # printing process id to SHOW that we're actually using MULTIPROCESSING 
    print("ID of main process: {}".format(os.getpid()))     

    shutil.copy(f'{src}\{file}', f'{dest}/') 

if __name__ == "__main__": 

    files = os.listdir(src) # Getting the files to copy

    for file in files:
        # creating a process per file 
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=copy_instance, args=(file, )) 

        # starting processes 
        p1.start()
```

Make sure to have the permission to copy in `dest` directory and try to use `absolute path` for both source and destination directory

Comment: Yea sure, with some minor changes and needed upgrades it works. This doesnt deal with folders so some changes we made to include that. Thanks.

Comment: any particular reason what shutil.copytree doent work here?

Comment: I realized you can use `copytree` to copy folders and create multiple process to handle it, but remember that's not the main idea but how to divide a unique process into multiples. In short, whatever function you decide to use, you have implement in several process that run at the same time e.g. with a for loop